# Refresh frequency using socket - iOS swift

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, swift, sockets

i'm new to iOS dev, it's only my second application, but i didn't make it this time. So, i need suggestion and tips to see how things really works

i'm trying to developpe an app which uses sharedMemory data of a game and sent it over sockets to an iphone.

I proceed this way :
1- func Initnetwork : Connect to the IP, and port and open input, output streams
2- func SendRequest : Send a message to the server ( running on windows in Cpp )
    Notes : I use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timer:0.0166) for sendRequest , to keep getting data from server
3- func Stream : To handle NSTreamEvent : if it hasBytes, it allocate a buffer and proceed to read the inputStream, then parse data with NSJsonSerialization, extracting data from and then refreshing labels in the main_queue

Problem : this kind of app need to refresh at high freq, so when running the app, everything is lagging, and i'm getting a refresh every 1 or 2 seconds later, i tried with timer = 0.1, it didn't work.

I'm asking for help because , i don't really know wich way i have to take to fix this problem ( multi thread, new server , idk ).
On the simulator, app keep the CPU working at his highest level 99, and i don't think it should perform like

here is what kind of app i'm trying to make : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33sXgUUgoWI

Comment: Pinging the server for data introduces some latency (one round trip plus the time it takes the server to gather the data and send it) - stream the data instead. You probably also want to avoid TCP and instead implement your own streaming protocol on top of UDP.

Comment: Okay i will look for that streaming protocol,
But i've been analyzing my code, i put a button on the main screen and kept touching it, it doesn't respond.
So i think it is related to NSTimer and the handler function. but how can the app on the link i posted, can handle such data, while mine is only 5 or 6 variables to handle and it s lagging as hell.

Comment: I finally made it :DD
i dove into the source code, and analyzed my functions, found a variable that keeps getting bigger and bigger, also some useless function i erased and VOILA :D, even CPU drop down to normal percentage